# Is there a local version of chatgpt that does not propagate any data out of the EU to comply with the GDPR?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am thinking of using chatgpt in my professional endevours, however as a EU citisen we are bound to the GDPR. What ways can I use it? Are there any models for local instalation? Are there any GDPR comling API accesses?

I am reading the API documentation but they do not seem to mention it expicitly, maybe i missed it however.

Answer (score 0):

after some serious digging i found that:

> **Do you offer EU data residency?** Not presently. We continue to explore the feasibility and impact of enabling localized data storage.

https://openai.com/policies/api-data-usage-policies